# d3: linearly interpolate only close-enough points

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Suppose I have an array of values with corresponding dates, `[{date: d1, value: v1}, ..., {date: dn, value: vn}]`, that I'd like to visualize using d3.js. As long as subsequent measurements are within a certain time range, for example not more than a week apart, I am happy with d3 interpolating between the measurements.

However, when subsequent records are farther apart, I don't want d3 to connect them. What would be the easiest way to achieve this?

Comment: What's your overall goal? Drawing a trend (line) chart with gaps in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is not exactly clear: by "interpolate", I believe you mean "connecting the dots".

If you use a time scale for your x axis, D3 will automatically connect the dots for you and create a line (an SVG `path` element), regardless the time separation in the data points. But there is a way for making "gaps" in that line: using [`line.defined()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/README.md#line_defined). According to the API:

> If defined is specified, sets the defined accessor to the specified function or boolean and returns this line generator.

The problem is, for this approach to work, you'll have to set a given value (let's say, `null`) in your dataset, between the dates in which you don't want to draw the line (that is, the dates that are not *close enough*, as you say in your question). You can do this manually or using a function.

This is a working demo: in my dataset, my data jumps from 7-Oct to 17-Oct (more than 1 week). So, I just created a `null` value in any date between these two (in my demo, 16-Oct). Then, in the line generator, the line jumps this `null` value, using `defined`:

```
d3.line().defined(function(d){return d.value != null;})
```

The result is that the line jumps from 7-Oct to 17-Oct:

```js
var data = [{date: "1-Oct-16",value: 14},
{date: "2-Oct-16",value: 33},
{date: "3-Oct-16",value: 12},
{date: "4-Oct-16",value: 43},
{date: "5-Oct-16",value: 54},
{date: "6-Oct-16",value: 71},
{date: "7-Oct-16",value: 32},
{date: "16-Oct-16",value: null},
{date: "17-Oct-16",value: 54},
{date: "18-Oct-16",value: 14},
{date: "19-Oct-16",value: 34},
{date: "20-Oct-16",value: 32},
{date: "21-Oct-16",value: 56},
{date: "22-Oct-16",value: 24},
{date: "23-Oct-16",value: 42},
{date: "24-Oct-16",value: 52},
{date: "25-Oct-16",value: 66},
{date: "26-Oct-16",value: 34},
{date: "27-Oct-16",value: 62},
{date: "28-Oct-16",value: 48},
{date: "29-Oct-16",value: 51},
{date: "30-Oct-16",value: 42}];

var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%d-%b-%y");

data.forEach(function (d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
});

var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 500)
    .attr("height", 200);
  
var xScale = d3.scaleTime().range([20, 480]);
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([180, 10]);

xScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
    return d.date;
    }));
yScale.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
    return d.value;
    })]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%d"));

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);

var baseline = d3.line()
   .defined(function(d){return d.value != null;})
    .x(function (d) {
      return xScale(d.date);
    })
    .y(function (d) {
      return yScale(d.value);
    });
  
svg.append("path") // Add the valueline path.
.attr("d", baseline(data))
.attr("fill", "none")
.attr("stroke", "teal");

svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,180)")
    .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(20,0)")
.attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to draw a broken line chart, then I don't think interpolation is what you're looking for. Building a custom SVG path is probably the way to go. See an example here:

https://bl.ocks.org/joeldouglass/1a0b2e855d2bedc24c63e396b04c8e36