# d3.line().defined(), but for segments between points

Tags: javascript, d3.js

currently I am trying to wrap my head around some d3 stuff. As far as I understand, the `.line().defined()` function only allows me to indicate whether a certain data point is defined or not. But that is not what I want. Allow me to explain:

I have some data points from a sensor that all look like this (simplified, it provides more values than that): `{"timestamp": 1617722059, "value": 103}`. My data only consists of those. Now I want to plot them, getting the last *[time interval]* available in the database to d3. It might be that the sensor was offline in between and didn't submit values. In that case, I don't want my graph to be defined. The problem is, every data point I have means the graph *is* defined there.

**How can I specify that if two neighbouring points are more than `n` seconds apart, then there should be no line segment?** I could imagine going through the sorted data set and adding null points wherever two are too far apart, but that feels horribly wrong. There should be a way to do this in d3, right?

Comment: Maybe the right way is to normilize your data before plotting it by calculating the values for every N whole seconds (for each 'normilized' timestamp take 2 closest timestamps and set their average value to it)

Comment: Hm, I kind of doubt that: While I could bucket them when looking at larger time frames, if I want to have the highest possible resolution, filling in extra points would simply unnecessarily blow up the data to be processed, just for exchanging a svg [L]ine for a [M]ove command...

Comment: *"I could imagine going through the sorted data set and adding null points wherever two are too far apart, but that feels horribly wrong. There should be a way to do this in d3, right?"* Not really, since your use case is quite rare. Also, have in mind that D3 is quite low level: it's just a library, not a charting tool, so the user has to create pretty much everything by themselves. That said, your *"wrong*" solution is probably the best one. Coincidently, that was what I proposed almost 5 years ago: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39750744/5768908

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Interesting, thank you for your perspective! I guess this is the way to go then. One other thought, won't it be tedious to process when I want to add polling data live? It might happen that old points get submitted later, those would have to be inserted and such filler points would have to be recalculated. Is that still the best approach I can have?

Comment: @PeterNerlich for inserting the old points in the correct position you'll have to sort/bisect the array anyway, so adding the null values will be no big additional burden.